# Get cart item details for logged in customer Magento REST API

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api

I want to get the list of items in a customer's shopping cart through REST API. I am using `GET /V1/carts/mine` but not getting the shopping cart item list. What will be the best way to get it with thumbnail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GET /rest/default/V1/carts/<cartID>/items` and you will get the list of items from a cart specified by its cart/quote ID

Response format is:

```json
[
    {
        "item_id": 149,
        "sku": "24-UG01",
        "qty": 1,
        "name": "Quest Lumaflex&trade; Band",
        "price": 17,
        "product_type": "simple",
        "quote_id": "56"
    },
    {
        "item_id": 150,
        "sku": "24-UG03",
        "qty": 1,
        "name": "Harmony Lumaflex&trade; Strength Band Kit ",
        "price": 20,
        "product_type": "simple",
        "quote_id": "56"
    }
]
```